# Ошибка ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Вот мой код:

```
public class DBConnectionProvider {

private static DBConnectionProvider provider;

private String dbDriver;
private String dbUrl;
private String dbUsername;
private String dbPassword;

private Connection connection;

private DBConnectionProvider() {
    try {
        loadProperties();
        Class.forName(dbDriver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to " +
                "initialize DB Connection Provider", e);
    }
}

private void loadProperties() throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\IdeaProjects\\Design\\src\\main\\resources\\db\\config.properties\""));


    dbDriver = properties.getProperty("db.driver");
    dbUrl = properties.getProperty("db.url");
    dbUsername = properties.getProperty("db.username");
    dbPassword = properties.getProperty("db.password");
```

[image: а вот и еррор]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в собранном проекте у вас нету драйвера, положите его туда и ошибка уйдет

Comment: Спасибо большое но я нашел причина кстати если у кому то возникает этот проблем сделайте следующее!!! в  IntellijIdea вверхном  панеле нарисовано какой то окошки если считать с правой это будет 4 нажмите на нее и зайдите раздел Artifact и там на правом окошке есть lib и нажмите два раз каждому и нажмите Apply и ok ! все

Comment: @v.hovhannisyan этим действием вы добавили библиотеку в classpath, поэтому она и работает.